# Invalid QuerySet.dates() despite having pytz and mysql timezones

Tags: django

I've done:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

As per:

```
mysql> select count(*) from `mysql`.`time_zone_name`;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     1778 |
+----------+
```

And my env has pytz:

```
$ pip list | grep pytz
pytz (2014.2)
```

But I'm still getting

> ValueError: Database returned an invalid value in QuerySet.datetimes(). Are time zone definitions for your database and pytz installed?

What could be the cause?

Comment: Could you provide some of your Django code to help understand the situation.  The model and queryset woudl be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had the same problem. Rebooting the server was the final step. Who would have thought? I was relying on touching the wsgi file, but the problem is not fixed without restarting the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

default-time-zone is probably not set in your my.cnf file. Try adding

```
default-time-zone = 'UTC'
```

to your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in `[mysqld]` section.

Comment: After rebooting the server with a `default-time-zone`, the problem disappeared.

Comment: **be careful** it should be after: `[mysqld]` tag

Comment: it didn't worked for me on MYSQL Community 5.7.20. Changing it to `default_time_zone='+00:00'` fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem solved by flushing MySQL after importing time-zones.

```
mysql> flush tables;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```