# MySQL query from docs with timezones doesn't appear to work in MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql

According to [the documentation for CONVERT_TZ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) I should be able to type in:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET');
```

and get

```
'2004-01-01 13:00:00'
```

However on my server I don't. I get `NULL`. It works if I replace `'GMT'` and `'MET'` with `'+00:00'` etc. `'UTC'` appears to be an unknown timezone. What is going on? in my my.cnf I have

```
'default_time_zone' = '+00:00'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that exact page you linked to:

> **Note**
>   To use named time zones such as 'MET' or 'Europe/Moscow', the time zone tables must be properly set up. See [Section 10.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html), for instructions.